# Passing parameters to CRYSTAL REPORTS via C# in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, crystal-reports

I am new to Crystal Reports. I have designed a Crystal Report by following this link: [Crystal Report with SQL Stored Procedure Parameter and Visual Studio](http://dotnetmentors.com/reporting/crystal-report-with-stored-procedure-parameter-and-visual-studio.aspx)
What I need to do is pass different ID's (Input value of the SP) to the SP that I connected with the Crystal Report.

This is the code I have which passes the ID to the Crystal Report :

```
        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        string QuotationID = ViewState["QUOTATION_ID"].ToString();
        ReportDocument reportDocument = new ReportDocument();
        ParameterField paramField = new ParameterField();
        ParameterFields paramFields = new ParameterFields();
        ParameterDiscreteValue paramDiscreteValue = new ParameterDiscreteValue();


       
        paramField.Name = "@id";


        paramDiscreteValue.Value = QuotationID;

        paramField.CurrentValues.Add(paramDiscreteValue);
        paramFields.Add(paramField);

        
        paramFields.Add(paramField);

        CrystalReportViewer1.ParameterFieldInfo = paramFields;

        string reportPath = Server.MapPath("~/CrystalReport.rpt");

        reportDocument.Load(reportPath);

       
        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = reportDocument;
        }
```

But whenever I click the button it asks for the ID...[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To set parameter on crystal I always do it this way:

```
ReportDocument reportDocument = new ReportDocument();
reportDocument.Load(reportPath);
reportDocument.SetParameterValue("@id", QuotationID);
```

if you want to convert your report to a pdf:

```
var exportOptions = reportDocument.ExportOptions;
exportOptions.ExportDestinationType = ExportDestinationType.NoDestination;
exportOptions.ExportFormatType = ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat;
var req = new ExportRequestContext {ExportInfo = exportOptions};
var stream = reportDocument.FormatEngine.ExportToStream(req);
```

this returns you back a filestream that you can open from the aspx page.