# Sorting and grouping a Crystal report by a specific date-parameter using visual C#

Tags: sql-server, crystal-reports

What I have:

- An sql db with employee data , along with the date on which the entry
  was made.
- A visual c# form which lets me do various things , such as    add ,
  edit and delete from and to the sql db.

What I need to do:

- Have a Crystal report showing only the results of the employees(from
  the sql db) whose entry was made between the dates specified by me on
  the form ,after pressing a button on the form.(check the link)

I am new to crystal reports.  what Should I do?

Below is how my form looks like :

[image]

Comment: are you want to create new crystal report or you need sql query for crystal report? or you want to whole functionality from button click to show proper report?

Comment: I want to show a sorted and grouped(with my desired specifications) crystal report ,after clicking the button.

Comment: have you tried sorting in crystal reports?

Comment: What i want to do is to group the desired sql queries in a crystal report , and Ignore all others. Say , I want all the employee queries which were added between 1st june,2015 and 8th june,2015. No other query has to be displayed on the crystal report

Comment: what i am finding hard to figure out is how to take the input parameters from the user and implement on a crystal report.

Answer (score 0):

Its simple dear, you just set the parameter same as we done for sql command while fetching the sql data.

```
ReportDocument reportDocument = new ReportDocument();
reportDocument.Load(reportPath);
reportDocument.SetParameterValue("@id", QuotationID);
```

You can check this links.

[passing parameter to the CRYSTAL REPORT through C# in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19838307/passing-parameter-to-the-crystal-report-through-c-sharp-in-asp-net)

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5492/Passing-Parameters-to-Crystal-Reports-at-Runtime

Comment: sorry for the late comment ,I was somewhere without internet. I still dont understand(i am new) do i have to make a stored procedure in sql?

Answer (score 0):

ok try this:

you need to create parameters in crystal reports of date datatype and use those in record selection formula to activate those.

This will pop up a window while preview that ask for the input from user and what the user has given input only that data will be retrived and displayed and internally in crystal report you can sort by date.

Comment: I know CR as a standalone not by using code.. in CR you can see the parameters to the right side of the crystal reports... create those and implement as suggested....you will be able to achieve your requirement.

Comment: The issue is that the parameters are variable , inputted from the form application. I can sort and group while creating a crystal report but am not being able to do what I mentioned before.No worries though , this is not a necessity of the program .

Comment: No idea on coding...sorry