# Filtering records based on combo box using crystal report?

Tags: c#

I'm just wondering if there is some kind of way to filter data by the value of the combo box? I'm really new to crystal report and I'm kinda stumped on this problem. I specifically need to filter the record shown based on the month inside the combo box. I have no idea how to implement this.

Can you guys direct me on what to do? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solutions is to add a parameter to the report design, set the record selection formula to use that parameter, and set the parameter value in your code.

If you search for "Passing parameters to crystal reports" you'll find many good resources.

Comment: thank you! I'll try to read resources online. Haven't found one yet that involves what I'm trying to do

Comment: Here is a useful thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19838307/passing-parameters-to-crystal-reports-via-c-sharp-in-asp-net